# On whatever amount of money (that) you have

Tags: vocabulary

How to make the following expression sound natural (and be grammatical)?

> This bank account gives 2% on whatever amount of money that you have in your account.

For example, would it be more natural to say "has a 2% yield" instead of "gives 2%"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a little on what reading level you are aiming for - 'yield' might be too technical for some audiences, and the grammar of your example is a little 'off' to my ears. Saying "amount of money" in this context is a little redundant, either word would be perfectly understandable on its own.

Typical for a UK bank advert might be: "This account pays 2% interest on the account balance."

Banking practices in the USA are very different though, so probably have different standard phrases too.

Comment: If I want to say specifically "on whatever amount (that) you have", do I need "that"? I think I've heard similar constructions (in different contexts) with "that", but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user91073  As I was saying about "amount of money" it would be rather redundant to be so explicit in this particular example, but no, 'that' isn't strictly necessary, but would tend to keep the grammar purists happy.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding redundancy, I took your correction into account and replaced "amount of money" by "amount" in the previous comment.